# How to Compress Public Key with OpenSSL / Bash

Tags: public-key, openssl, bash

I generate the private and the public keys in Shell like that:

```
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -rand /dev/random -genkey -noout -out private-key.pem
openssl ec -in private-key.pem -outform DER | tail -c +8 | head -c 32 | xxd -p -c 32 > bitcoin_private_key.pem
openssl ec -in private-key.pem -pubout -outform DER | tail -c 65 | xxd -p -c 65 > bitcoin_public_key.pem
```

Then I can take the public key X with:

```
head -c 66 bitcoin_public_key.pem | tail -c 64
```

And the last byte of Y with:

```
tail -c 3 bitcoin_public_key.pem
```

The compressed public key must be `0x02 + X` for an even last byte of `Y` and `0x03 + X` for an odd one.

How to check if the last Y's byte is odd or even?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of compressing 'by hand' you can have OpenSSL do it:

```
openssl ec -in privatekey.pem -pubout -conv_form compressed -outform der | tail -c 33 | xxd -p -c 33 >compressedpub.hex
```

And .pem is *usually* used to mean PEM format, while the files you are creating are totally not at all or in any way PEM format, so that's very misleading and confusing. I used .hex for my example, but there are other reasonable possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You just check if Y is divisible by 2 (i.e Y % 2 == 0). It's the default parity concept…